# GMail composer links don't work on Android

Tags: android, gmail, mailto

I am using GMail links like

```
https://mail.google.com/?view=cm&to=some@email.com
```

or

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=mailto%3A%3Fto%3Dsome%40email.com
```

to simplify writing mails with prefilled receiver, subject, and body content. This works fine on desktop, but when I open either type of link in Firefox or Chrome on Android, it will just go to my inbox instead of opening a composer.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Is the link opened in an app or from a website? If it is opened in an app, the intents should be used accordingly

Comment: Well I'm letting some service post the link to discord and open it from there or copy the link to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use mailto instead

```
mailto:some@email.com?subject=test&body=test
```

This will allow android and iOS to automatically use intents to offer the user a choice of email clients or selecting the default email client.

It will also use your default mail client on your pc. If gmail is not your default, you can make it so that links will open in your gmail browser